# Could not hardlink copy Xcode 8.2.1

Tags: xcode, error-handling

I am having a problem running my code.

```
Could not hardlink copy /Users/<Username>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C85FAE3C-20FE-4424-8B1B-9FF8DC9C0E62/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F80CC986-9ED4-45A1-B755-D4022339A745/JustRestourant.app to /Users/<Username>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C85FAE3C-20FE-4424-8B1B-9FF8DC9C0E62/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.vvASN9/extracted/Payload/JustRestourant.app with manifest /Users/<Username>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C85FAE3C-20FE-4424-8B1B-9FF8DC9C0E62/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.vvASN9/extracted/com.apple.deltainstallcommands.com.custom.JustRestourant
```

Error = http://prntscr.com/g0rxvd
I am new to coding so please go easy.

Comment: I can't answer this but I can tell your that's not how you spell "Restaurant" :P

Answer (score 0):

Can you open the simulator program?  If not reinstall Xcode.

Comment: I can open simulator in other xcode project just not this one